# Kiosk Thermal printer

Tags: debian

I'm trying to make the termal printer below to work with CUPS. The supplier emailed me the printer's drivers. Now CUPS is recognizing the printer, but when I try to print out anything, the job state in CUPS displays the message: `"/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoprinter failed"`

http://www.syncotech.com/en/products/show.php?id=58

Can anyone help me? I cannot figure out what's wrong just by looking in the error_log file [`/var/log/cups/error_log`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14005650/).

Comment: Can you access any log files. They usaully have more infromation there. [Read this](http://hplipopensource.com/node/225)

Comment: The log files would be in `/var/log/`, either in messages or the cups sub-folder.